# Can't restore password for my AppleID

Tags: macos, apple-id

I can't restore my AppleID.

On stage sending text message I got

```
This action could not be completed
Your request could not be completed because of an error. Try again later
```

But I have wait for quit a long time. Is there any way to contact apple support by email? Or waht should I do in that case?

UPDATE

Text message has come but I got another error

```
This action could not be completed
Account recovery is not available because of a server error. Start over and try again
```

Comment: It's going to be a busy weekend for Apple servers, with iOS 13 just released. It might just be a 'sit & wait'.

Comment: @Tetsujin - oh, thanks. I was in panic a bit